# I try to compile my ASP.NET MVC code, but I get a System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to compile my ASP.NET MVC code, but I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

The program works, but in the confirmation of my form, I get this error. Please help me solve it.

[image]

Comment: Suggest reading [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/8017690) before posting the question by providing the Minimal, Reproducible Example with code snippet.

Comment: Show us your code in the controller that prepares the data and then returns this view - that's where we'd see if you're getting the data ready correctly...

Answer (score -1):

you information is limited, but base on your image, `@Model` is NULL. you should **initialize** it before use.

Comment: Ok, Nima. Thank you for your answer, but here is the extract of my form, which must collect information...           <!--Creation du formulaire...-->
    <form asp-action="RsvpForm" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
        <p>
            <label asp-for="Name">Ton nom:</label>
            <input asp-for="Name" />
        </p>